# VC++ included headers cannot be found

Tags: visual-c++

I downloaded sample code that uses a 'header only' library and even though I have included the library path in my VC++ project, I keep getting the error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp': No such file or directory
```

Library header files location:

```
D:\websocketpp
D:\websocketpp\config
```

Here are the first few lines of the example program echo_server.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/server.hpp>
```

The included files do exist in the directories above.  I have specified the directories as follows:

Visual C++ Directories / Include Directories /

```
D:\websocketpp
```

C/C++ / General / Additional Include Directories

```
D:\websocketpp\config
```

Does someone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid mistake.  I moved the entire directory structure into a new folder:

```
D:\websocket\websocket
D:\websocket\websocket\config
```